# Rails migration paths introduced through engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, rails-engines

I have a rails application that runs a rails engine by explicitly declaring it in the Gemfile. I have a script set up to install the migrations from the engine via: `rake railties:install:migrations` and then migrates. When I run the script, the migrations are installed but when the migrations run I get a DuplicateMigration error. I investigated this further and saw that

`Rails.application.paths['db/migrate'].to_a`

resulted in:

`["/src/db/migrate","/bundle/bundler/gems/my_engine-w8ejw9jf/db/migrate"]`

Somehow the migration path from the bundle directory is getting added to the Rails application paths. Where does this happen? Is there a way I can prevent the migration paths from my bundle directory from being included in the application paths?

Answer (score 5):

Okay I did some more digging and it turns out that this is actually being done in the Engine itself. In the `engine.rb` file there is some logic that changes the paths that are autoloaded. The core logic was as follows:

```
 class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
   isolate_namespace MyEngine

   initializer :append_migrations do |app|
     unless app.root.to_s.match root.to_s
       config.paths["db/migrate"].expanded.each do |expanded_path|
         app.config.paths["db/migrate"] << expanded_path
       end
     end
   end
end
```

This was taking the expanded paths of the migration files, and shoving them into the paths config. This is why I was seeing `/bundle/bundler/gems/mycoolgem-w8ejw9jf/db/migrate` in the paths config.